# How to reduce substantial lag Selenium Webdriver (C#) when executing on a Siebel Application?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, crm, siebel

I'll preface this by saying that I'm looking for a solution to the slow performance, not an alternative to Webdriver.  Unfortunately, that is not an option.

In short, the Siebel application takes a *very* long time to load.  When manually logging in, it takes around 5 seconds to get authenticated and just a few seconds when navigating through pages.  When running automation, it takes 1-2 minutes to log in and 10-20 seconds to navigate.

I'm not entirely constrained to a specific browser / version.  I've had the most success with Chrome and Firefox.

Is there any sort of way to speed this up?  Maybe something I can change with my driver settings, browser settings, libraries I can utilize, etc.?

Thanks,

Steven

Update: this is the wait script I'm `public static void WaitForPageToLoad()
        {
            bool pageComplete = false;
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    pageComplete = (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)TestBase.Driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete");
                } while (!pageComplete);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Page never loaded");
                System.Console.WriteLine("Exception detail: " + e);
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Steve, The first thing I would check for are explicit sleeps in the WebDriver scripts.  Get rid of them and use [wait.until(condition)](https://github.com/Selenium/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/test/support/UI/DefaultWaitTest.cs).  When you tell me that their are no sleeps then I will take another swing. :-)

Comment: No explicit sleeps!  I'm actually waiting for the DOM to load for my implicit wait script.  Updated question with the wait script

Comment: You want to take advantage of selenium's wait.until() functionality.  What you are doing in your loop, with no sleeps, is acting like a buzz saw on your CPU.  Take a look [here](https://github.com/mikejramsey56/cuc_jav_webdriver/blob/master/src/test/java/helpers/HelpWithJavascriptLibraries.java) for how I solved the general wait for page load problem.